# Foolproof way to get Android User's Personal Phone Number?

Tags: java, android

I currently use this:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = 
(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

Which works like 85% of the time. But on some phones it returns nothing. I believe this is due to differences in Sim cards.

Is there somewhere else on the Android platform to gain this information reliably?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that not all Android devices are phones or have phone numbers. tablets wouldn't have that value.  or.. tablets would use Google Voice for their "phone number" instead..

Comment: It would be interesting to answer the question *Does this device have a phone number?* definitively though.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. As far as I know, `getLineNumber()` returns the Number that is shown in the About Phone screen but it doesn't always work. The api for `getLineNUmber()` even says this, it returns null when the phone number isn't available.